# how to determine div's class aspx behind with if statement

Tags: asp.net

I want to determine div class if cevaplanma_sayisi bigger than 0 the div's class="xx" and cevaplanma_sayisi not bigger than 0 the div's class="yy"

```
<div  <%# ((int)Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi")>0) ? {class="xx"} : {class="yy"} %> >
```

my code is above but something is wrong How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 <div <%# ((int)Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi")) > 0 ? "class='xx'" : "class='yy'" %> >
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "<%#" supposed to be used to bind data ? I'd use the following syntax instead :

```
<div  <%= ((int)Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi")>0) ? {class="xx"} : {class="yy"} %> >
```

But ideally :

```
<div class="<%= ((int)Eval("Cevaplanma_Sayisi")>0) ? xx : yy %>" >
```

I've not checked those code so take them with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

well you could do that in code behind

```
<div id="myId" runat="server"></div>
```

in code behind

```
 protected void PageLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         If(cevaplanma_sayisi > 0)
            myId.Attributes["class"] =   xx
         else 
            myId.Attributes["class"] =   yy
    }
```